# Server no gulp e no grunt

Tags: grunt, gulpjs

Tenho pesquisado mas acredito não estar fazendo as perguntas certas. Quero utilizar o gulp ao invés do grunt mas como eu rodo um "grunt server" usando gulp? Pq o watch do gulp não tem nada a ver com usar uma porta de acesso certo?

Meu problema com o grunt é de configuração. É impossível fazer ele funcionar eu já desisti. O gulp roda legal mas não encontro esse comando. Na verdade nem sei se ele existe..  alguém pode me tirar essa dúvida?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, o método `watch` do gulp indica ao mesmo para que assista as mudanças que ocorrerem nos arquivos ou diretórios passados para que ele execute uma determina tarefa quando houver.

O comando `grunt server` na verdade executa uma tarefa com o nome `server` que fica disponível através de algum plugin, geralmente o [grunt-contrib-connect](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect) que é utilizado para esse fim.

Um plugin equivalente a ele no gulp seria o [gulp-connect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-connect). Para utilizá-lo você precisa ter a CLI do gulp instalado globalmente e também instalado localmente no diretório do seu projeto e também o plugin.

Para fazer isto execute o comando dentro da pasta do seu projeto (após ter instalado o gulp globalmente) :

`npm install --save-dev gulp gulp-connect`

Depois basta criar o arquivo `gulpfile.js`. Vou assumir que você já tenha seu arquivo `package.json` criado, se não use o comando `npm init` e siga as instruções passadas por ele para fazê-lo.

No seu arquivo `gulpefile.js` basta chamar o plugin utilizando o `require` do nodejs e criar a tarefa responsável por iniciar o servidor seguindo a documentação do plugin:

```
var gulp    = require('gulp'), // Faz a chamada do gulp
connect = require('gulp-connect'); // Faz a chamada do plugin gulp-connect responsável por iniciar o servidor

gulp.task('server', function() {  // Criamos uma tarefa chamada 'server' responsável por iniciar o servidor na porta 8888
  connect.server({
    port: 8888 // A porta onde o servidor estará disponível 
  });
});

gulp.task('default', ['server']); // Aqui temos a terefa padrão que é executada ao rodar o comando gulp no terminal
```

Depois basta executar o comando `gulp` no terminal dentro do diretório do seu projeto e ele irá executar as tarefas, neste caso a de iniciar o servidor.

Em minha pasta de exemplo criei um arquivo `index.html` com uma mensagem simples para realmente saber se o servidor está funcionando ou não, e como esperado você pode ver funcionando na seguinte imagem:

[image: Print Screen do gulp funcionando]

Você pode ler a documentação do plugin para mais detalhes e outras funções que ele pode executar como por exemplo, LiveReload.

Comment: Wow Natan! Q resposta!!!  Tudo o q wu precisava! Muito obrigado mesmo!